# Read "time to fully charged"

Tags: c++, battery

I am testing several laptops with Windows installed and I need to write code that takes the time (in seconds or minutes) "until fully charged" - the value that windows shows, as well as the time until fully discharged. The value that indicates how many minutes until full discharge is contained in the PowerStatus.BatteryLifeRemaining Property.

I can't find where to read the time until fully charged. I don't want to calculate it, but to take the same value that Windows shows - i.e. A similar way to get this time to fully charged via Windows PowerShell would be helpful to me.

Comment: Perhaps you could look for an open source tool showing this information and look up in the source, how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows API doesn't provide a direct way to get the time until fully charged, as far as I know. I think the only possibility here is to calculate it. e.g. like this:

```
SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS sps;

int remainingPercent = 100 - sps.BatteryLifePercent;
int fullLifeTime = sps.BatteryFullLifeTime;
int timeUntilCharged = remainingPercent * fullLifeTime / 100;
```

Regards

Comment: On all my laptops sps.BatteryFullLifeTime is always -1 during the charge.